# jQuery IF and 'Radio' value question

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

I have a code that doesn't gives you to submit the form until all the fields are filled.

Now i have one field that is hidden unless the user checks the "client" option on the radio below it.

I need to know how can i check if the radio value is "client" and only then to force them to fill it in.

Here is the code that i came across with (the client part doesn't work while the normal fields are ok.):

```
jQuery(function(){

var defaultVal1 = jQuery("#appName").val();
var defaultVal2 = jQuery("#appID").val();
var defaultVal3 = jQuery("#aToken").val();
var cVal = jQuery("input[name='clientCheck']").value == "client";

jQuery(".button").click(function(e){

var newVal1 = jQuery("#appName").val(); 
var newVal2 = jQuery("#appID").val();   
var newVal3 = jQuery("#aToken").val();

    if(defaultVal1 === newVal1, defaultVal2 === newVal2, defaultVal3 === newVal3)
       {
           alert("Please fill out all the fields.");
           e.preventDefault();
       }
               if(cVal)
           {
              alert("You have selected a Client App - Please fill out the Client Name.");
              e.preventDefault();
           }

   });
```

Also i would like to know if i can specify the fields that they didn't filled out on the alert message.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(function(){


var defaultVal1 = jQuery("#appName").val();
var defaultVal2 = jQuery("#appID").val();
var defaultVal3 = jQuery("#aToken").val();
var cVal = jQuery('input:radio[name=cliencheck]:checked').val();

jQuery(".button").click(function(e){

 newVal1 = jQuery("#appName").val(); 
 newVal2 = jQuery("#appID").val();   
 newVal3 = jQuery("#aToken").val();
 cVal = jQuery('input:radio[name=cliencheck]:checked').val();

    if(!(newVal1===defaultVal1 ) || !(newVal1===defaultVal2 ) || !(newVal3===defaultVal3 ))
       {
           alert("Please fill out all the fields.");
           e.preventDefault();
       }         
       else if(cVal == 'client')
       {
              alert("You have selected a Client App - Please fill out the Client Name.");
              e.preventDefault();
       }

   });
```

Comment: The thing is that i have a default value on all the fields so that's the point of check (the fields aren't empty) so basically i need to check if the value equals to the default value and not if the value is empty.

Comment: mm. i edited the code. please check it :)

Comment: hmm it still doesn't work ;( . the normal alert is working perfect like before but seems like when i fill all the fields except the the client field i still can submit and nothing happens.

Comment: And when I'm trying to `alert(cVal)` it gets back as `undefined`.

Comment: I had a writing error in there (it was missing one letter) and now it works! thanks buddy.

Comment: hei , glad to help................ you are wel come :D :D :D :D